# Matching a list of sequences with common form

Tags: pattern-matching, sequence

I am trying to find a pattern that matches a list of sequences that share a common form. The sequence form is: 1 followed by zero or more nonzero integers, followed by 0. An example list is:

```
{1,3,2,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,1,4,0}
```

The closest thing I've struck on so far is this:

```
MatchQ[{1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {PatternSequence[1, s___ /; FreeQ[{s}, 0], 0] ..}]
```

which yields `True` in this case because the sequences are both the same. Is there a way to get the `s___` to apply uniquely to each instance in the `Repeated`? This would solve the problem. Other suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {1,3,2,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,1,4,0};

MatchQ[list, {PatternSequence[1, ___?(IntegerQ@# && Positive[#] &), 0] ...}]
```

> True

This is an interesting problem. I'm not sure how to solve it using `Condition` rather than `PatternTest`.